# Cannot access a disposed object. Object name: 'Icon', Error randomly in MonoGame when all I'm doing is generating tile sprites

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, monogame

I am learning MonoGame for the first time and I made a system that generates a map dictionary and spawns  tiles near the player and removes them when they are out of range.

This seems to work as expected but after I walk around for a bit I get this error:

> System.ObjectDisposedException: 'Cannot access a disposed object.
>   Object name: 'Icon'.'

Seemingly with no pattern. It shows up on the line:

```
public Tile(int X, int Y, string Type)
```

I am new to object oriented programming but couldn't understand the reasons for the error online as they seemed unrelated. If any more info is needed just ask and I will add it. I would be very grateful for some help.

The tile sprite:

```
//##Tile##
    public class Tile : Game
    {
        //##Default Varibles##
        public Vector2 Scale;
        public Vector2 Position;
        public Rectangle Rect;

        //##Initialise##
        public Vector2 GridPosition;
        public Tile(int X, int Y, string Type)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("StackTrace: '{0}'", Environment.StackTrace);

            //Position
            GridPosition = new Vector2(X, Y);
            Position = new Vector2(MainGame.instance.Graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / 2 - MainGame.instance.AssetManager.TileTextureList[0].Width / 2 + X * 64, MainGame.instance.Graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight / 2 - MainGame.instance.AssetManager.TileTextureList[0].Height / 2 + Y * 64);

            //Rect
            Rect = new Rectangle((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y, MainGame.instance.AssetManager.TileTextureList[0].Width, MainGame.instance.AssetManager.TileTextureList[0].Height);
        }

        //##EveryFrame##
        public void Update()
        {
            //Function Calls


            //Update Rectangle
            Rect.Location = new Point((int)Position.X, (int)Position.Y);
        }

        //##Draw##
        public void Draw()
        {
            MainGame.instance.MainLayer.Draw(texture: MainGame.instance.AssetManager.TileTextureList[0], position: Position, color: Color.White);
        }
    }
```

Stack trace I think:

```
StackTrace: '   at System.Environment.GetStackTrace(Exception e, Boolean needFileInfo)
   at System.Environment.get_StackTrace()
   at ThisGame.Sprites.Tile..ctor(Int32 X, Int32 Y, String Type) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\C# Projects\MonoGame\FalseGold\FalseGold\Sprites.cs:line 226
   at ThisGame.Functions.LoadTiles() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\C# Projects\MonoGame\FalseGold\FalseGold\Functions.cs:line 80
   at ThisGame.Sprites.Update() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\C# Projects\MonoGame\FalseGold\FalseGold\Sprites.cs:line 30
   at ThisGame.MainGame.Update(GameTime gameTime) in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\C# Projects\MonoGame\FalseGold\FalseGold\Game.cs:line 101
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.DoUpdate(GameTime gameTime)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Tick()
   at MonoGame.Framework.WinFormsGameWindow.TickOnIdle(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponent.FDoIdle(Int32 grfidlef)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
   at MonoGame.Framework.WinFormsGameWindow.RunLoop()
   at MonoGame.Framework.WinFormsGamePlatform.RunLoop()
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run(GameRunBehavior runBehavior)
   at Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game.Run()
   at ThisGame.Program.Main() in C:\Users\User\Desktop\Coding\C# Projects\MonoGame\FalseGold\FalseGold\Program.cs:line 12'
Exception thrown: 'System.ObjectDisposedException' in System.Drawing.dll
An unhandled exception of type 'System.ObjectDisposedException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Cannot access a disposed object.
```

The game working:
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbr8a.png)

If I don't walk around for a bit it doesn't crash.

Comment: Full stack trace, please.

Comment: It's everything that follows the first part of the error message. It lists different methods that were called (and typically their line numbers) in the chain up to the point where the error was thrown.

Comment: Is the code you've included from line 226 of Sprites.cs?

Comment: The code goes from line 214-251. I'll add the stack trace to the code.

Comment: I have added an image of it working for context. I don't know if I did the stack trace right.

Answer (score 0):

I would appear that you are creating multiple instances of the internal `game` class.

When one of them falls out of scope the destructor of the `game` class destroys the graphics manager object thus invalidating the pointers to the internal drawing structures.

Remove the `: Game` from the end of all classes except `MainGame`. This should fix your issues.